# How ring expansion is possible here?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, stability, carbocation

Recently I have came across this question.

[image]

I went with the 3rd option as ring expansion cannot occur due to the formed stable 3 degree carbocation. But the answer key claims 4th option. How can product through the ring expansion be the major product  here ? As the 3 degree carbocation is stable, and if ring expansion happens, a 3 degree carbocation to 2 degree carbocation transition should occur (although in the end 3 degree carbocation would form) as I have written in the mechanism for this pathway here:

[image]

But this pathway has to undergo activation barrier for the 3 degree to 2 degree carbocation transition. So how would this product be major product ? If the starting compound is a 4 membered or 3 membered ring, then the ring stability may be more dominating factor than the stability of the carbocation, but in this case it is a quite stable 5 membered ring.

Links:

[Ring expansion in cyclo compounds](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/136119/ring-expansion-in-cyclo-compounds)

[Carbocation rearrangement with ring expansion](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/169975/carbocation-rearrangement-with-ring-expansion?rq=1)

Comment: All steps are reversible until you get the thermodynamically most stable product.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne Yes. But isn't the product through ring expansion a minor product ?

Comment: If it's minor would depend on conditions of reaction.